# Directory access denied -- in server(bluehost)?

Tags: codeigniter

When i completed my project in codeigniter and uploaded to server it show directory access denied? What to do ...i have configured in config file but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change read/write permissions for the directory hosting your codeigniter application. Refer to your hosting company's help section to see how this can be done.